# Blazor JS integration

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core, blazor

We have a client requirement wherein the client is planning to implement Blazor on his website. My product is basically a JS script which runs on the client side which goes in the head section of HTML. Now I read that Blazor uses C# instead of JS. So I wanted to know wherether there will be any issues with my script src going in the head section?

Comment: What is the head tag? Do you want to integret the javascript into the head tag? And you can share some necessary code.

Comment: @karney yes its a js code. Sample snippet:
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="url-of-script">
</head>
<body>...</body>
</html>
The script is served from a cdn which has all the js scripting included.

Answer (score 2):

You can reference the javascript in `pages/_Host.cshtml`.

[image]

Then in your razor compoment, you need to inject `IJSRuntime`, and use this method `JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("function", "parameter");`

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="trigger">Click me</button>

@code {

  private void trigger()
  {
    JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("method1", "this value");
  }
}
```

There are many other parameter you can refert to this [docuemnt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0#call-a-void-javascript-function).